# CefSharp ChromiumWebBrowser- allow user to zoom in/out

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-interface, view, cefsharp

I am using the `ChromiumWebBrowser` provided by the `CefSharp` library to allow users to view and interact with a website from within my C# application.

The website is currently displayed correctly, and the user is able to interact with it fully, as if they were viewing it in a standard web browser.

I now want to add the functionality to allow users to zoom in/ out when viewing the website from within my application, but I'm unsure how to do this... most of what I've found on the web seems to indicate that I should use the `LayoutTransform` attribute of the `<Grid>` tag, and then a `<ScaleTransform>` tag in my `XAML`, and I've tried this, but can't seem to get it working...

My `XAML` is as follows:

```
<Grid x:Name="grdBrowserHost" MinHeight="900" Height="Auto" MinWidth="1200" Width="Auto" Margin="0,0,0,0" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.LayoutTransform>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=_zoom}" ScaleY="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=_zoom}" />
    </Grid.LayoutTransform>
    <cefSharp:ChromiumWebBrowser Name="browser" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Grid.Row="0" Address="www.google.com" Margin="0,35,-0.2,0" />
</Grid>
```

How would I add the functionality to allow the user to zoom in and out on the content of the `cefSharp:ChromiumWebBrowser ...>` in this `XAML`? Ideally, I want them to be able to zoom in/ out by using 'Shift+'/'Shift-'/'Shift and Scroll'.

Anyone have any suggestions, or able to point me to an example of how this is implemented?

**Edit**

So I've managed to implement the functionality to some extent by adding a `slider` to the GUI:

```
<Slider x:Name="slider" Maximum="100" ValueChanged="zoom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1177,260,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

and using that to call a function that I've named `zoom()`- in which I set the `browser.ZoomLevel` attribute equal to `slider.Value`:

```
public void zoom(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    browser.ZoomLevel = slider.Value;
}
```

However, this currently works by clicking the `slider` object on the GUI, and dragging the cursor left/ right, but it seems to 'jump' the zoom from one value to the next as you move the slider, rather than changing it gradually/ making the view zoom in/ out smoothly.

How would I cause the display to zoom in/out smoothly as the user moves the slider, rather than jumping from 'normal view' to the maximum value (100)?

How can I add functionality to zoom in/ out using keyboard shortcuts (such as CTRL+ / CTRL-), rather than using a `slider`?

Comment: Anyone looking an answer for WPF: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66322895/3596441

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How would I cause the display to zoom in/out smoothly as the user
>   moves the slider, rather than jumping from 'normal view' to the
>   maximum value (100)?

For this you have to set the zoom level increment

```
browser.ZoomLevelIncrement = 0.5;
```

> How can I add functionality to zoom in/ out using keyboard shortcuts (such as CTRL+ / CTRL-), rather than using a slider?

Here the below codes used to Zoom In/Out using Ctrl+Mouse-wheel.

```
private void OnPreviewKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.RightCtrl || e.Key == Key.LeftCtrl)
    {
        isControlKeyPressed = false;
    }
}

private void OnKPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.RightCtrl || e.Key == Key.LeftCtrl)
    {
        isControlKeyPressed = true;
    }
}

private void OnMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    if (isControlKeyPressed)
    {
        if (e.Delta > 0 && browser.ZoomLevel <= maxZoomLevel)
        {
            browser.ZoomInCommand.Execute(null);
        }
        else if (e.Delta < 0 && browser.ZoomLevel >= minZoomLevel)
        {
            browser.ZoomOutCommand.Execute(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added keyboard zoom. In init section subscribe for events

```cs
cefBrowser.PreviewMouseWheel += CefBrowser_PreviewMouseWheel;
cefBrowser.KeyUp += CefBrowser_KeyUp;
```

I used `PreviewMouseWheel` to avoid scrolling during zoom (`e.Handled = true`).

```cs
private void CefBrowser_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e) {

  if (Keyboard.Modifiers != ModifierKeys.Control)
    return;

  if (e.Delta > 0)
    cefBrowser.ZoomInCommand.Execute(null);
  else
    cefBrowser.ZoomOutCommand.Execute(null);
  e.Handled = true;
}

private void CefBrowser_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {

  if (Keyboard.Modifiers != ModifierKeys.Control)
    return;

  if (e.Key == Key.Add)
    cefBrowser.ZoomInCommand.Execute(null);
  if (e.Key == Key.Subtract)
    cefBrowser.ZoomOutCommand.Execute(null);
  if (e.Key == Key.NumPad0)
    cefBrowser.ZoomLevel = 0;
}
```

So now cef zooming almost like chrome