# contents of the Chromium WebBrowser is blurry

Tags: c#, wpf, chromium, viewbox

I am currently doing a WPF project and I run into a problem. In my case, the UI is designed in the resolution of 1920 * 1080. I create a window and inside the window, I have a viewbox, in order to make the window suit well in different resolutions. Then I embed the Chromium WebBrowser in the viewbox. It looks find in the default resolution(1920 * 1080), however, it looks terrible when the whole window zooms, especially when the zoom scale is less than 1. Anyone ran into this situation before?
[image: description]
[image: description]

Comment: Could you please clarify what you *expect* as result of scaling?

Comment: Ok. Can you see the images? The first one is the normal one, while the second one is blurry. I can hardly read the texts. I hope that the texts show good in all solutions.

Comment: Typical air-space problem, it rescales a bitmap copy of the web page view, not the page itself.  Surely you didn't actually embed Chromium itself, we can't see your code.  I suspect [this Q+A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37681816/cefsharp-chromiumwebbrowser-allow-user-to-zoom-in-out) should be helpful.

Comment: In my case, the code looks like this:                                           <Viewbox Stretch="Fill">
        <Grid Height="350" Width="525">
            <cefSharp:ChromiumWebBrowser Name="browser" Address="www.XXXX.com" />
        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>                                                                                                       In normal case(resolution is 1920x1080), the texts shown in the browser looks fine. But When I run on a laptop(resolution is 1366×768), I will scale the whole window. As a result, the browser window resize, and the texts look blurry.

Answer (score 0):

First:
I would not recommend  a `ViewBox` for this control

Second:

It could probably be a issue of chromium solved [here](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/166)