# Allow user to zoom with mousewheel using the cefsharp browser

Tags: cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I am running cefsharp/75.  I want to turn on zooming with the ctrl key and the mousewheel.  My event handler is never triggered. And if you hold ctrl and use the mouse will the screen doesn't move.  So something inside the control and handling the event.  Is there just a setting I am missing?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no mouse handler and `Chromium` basically swallows all mouse related events, you can hook the low level `HWND`, it's not pretty though. See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/75/CefSharp.WinForms.Example/BrowserTabUserControl.cs#L299 for an example.

Answer (score 3):

I added mouse and keyboard zoom. In init section subscribe for events

```cs
cefBrowser.PreviewMouseWheel += CefBrowser_PreviewMouseWheel;
cefBrowser.KeyUp += CefBrowser_KeyUp;
```

I used `PreviewMouseWheel` to avoid scrolling during zoom (`e.Handled = true`).

```cs
private void CefBrowser_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e) {

  if (Keyboard.Modifiers != ModifierKeys.Control)
    return;

  if (e.Delta > 0)
    cefBrowser.ZoomInCommand.Execute(null);
  else
    cefBrowser.ZoomOutCommand.Execute(null);
  e.Handled = true;
}

private void CefBrowser_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {

  if (Keyboard.Modifiers != ModifierKeys.Control)
    return;

  if (e.Key == Key.Add)
    cefBrowser.ZoomInCommand.Execute(null);
  if (e.Key == Key.Subtract)
    cefBrowser.ZoomOutCommand.Execute(null);
  if (e.Key == Key.NumPad0)
    cefBrowser.ZoomLevel = 0;
}
```

So now cef zooming almost like chrome

Comment: This will only work for WPF,  where the question is likely about WinForms.

Comment: @amaitland Yes you are right my code is for WPF. I stuck with the same problem - mouse wheel event was not fire. And I found this question. Just want to share some information to help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Using `CefSharp.WinForms.NETCore v114.2.120` for my project, I was able to get it to work using `ChromiumWidgetNativeWindow` to handle the
`WM_MOUSEWHEEL` and `WM_MOUSEHWHEEL` WndProc messages.

```cs
ChromiumRenderWidgetHandleFinder.TryFindHandle(browser, out var chromeWidgetHostHandle);
NativeWindow = new ChromiumWidgetNativeWindow(browser, chromeWidgetHostHandle);
NativeWindow.OnWndProc(Browser_WndProc);
```

Here is where I handle the scrolling, where delta is the number of ticks of the scroll wheel, negative when scrolling down.

```cs
private bool Browser_WndProc(Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg is not 0x020A or 0x020E) // Mouse wheel
        return false;

    if ((m.WParam & 0x0008) == 0) // Ctrl pressed
        return false;

    short delta = (short)((short)(m.WParam >> 16 & 0xFFFF) / 120);
    ZoomLevel += zoomRate * delta;

    return true;
}
```

ZoomLevel is a property I defined to control the zoom of the browser

```cs
public double ZoomLevel
{
    get => _zoomLevel;
    set => browser.SetZoomLevel(_zoomLevel = value);
}
private double _zoomLevel = 1d;
```

It's important to note that fetching the handle will often fail if done right after creating the `ChromiumWebBrowser` instance. I got good results by waiting until after the first page navigation.

```cs
browser.LoadUrl(url);
await browser.WaitForNavigationAsync();

if (NativeWindow is null)
{
    ChromiumRenderWidgetHandleFinder.TryFindHandle(browser, out var chromeWidgetHostHandle);
    NativeWindow = new ChromiumWidgetNativeWindow(browser, chromeWidgetHostHandle);
    NativeWindow.OnWndProc(Browser_WndProc);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a WinForms solution:
Register a MouseEventHandler for the form:

```
this.MouseWheel += new MouseEventHandler(this.OnMouseWheel);

private void OnMouseWheel(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{
  Control ctrl = FindControlAtCursor(this);
  if (ctrl == null) return; 
if(control is CEFBrowser)
{
  var zoomLevel = CefSharp.WebBrowserExtensions.GetZoomLevelAsync((ChromiumWebBrowser)ctrl).Result;
  zoomLevel += e.Delta > 0 ? 0.1 : -0.1;
  (ctrl as CefSharp.IWebBrowser).GetBrowser().GetHost().SetZoomLevel(zoomLevel);
}
}
```

It works OK except for one thing: after performing Zoom then scrolling the page, you must click anywhere outside the CEF control before zooming again.